# Disable caching in umbracoHelper.TypedContent

Tags: umbraco, umbraco7

Simple line of code that returns IPublishedContent:

```
var cachedNode = umbracoHelper.TypedContent(1234);
```

My issues is that the code above returns published content only whereas there're cases where I would rather want unpublished content to be returned (along with published). For example, in integration tests I need to perform testing against both published and unpublished nodes.

One of my ideas was: `umbracoContext.InPreviewMode = true`, but that didn't work.

Any help on the subject?

Comment: What do you mean with cached content? UmbracoHelper returns the currently published content. If you want to access the saved (but not published) data, you'll want to use the ContentService

Comment: As per the comment above if you don't want to access the cached content you need to use the ContentService, however, I advise against using that on your front end as it will keep hitting your database unnecessarily.

Comment: Yes, I meant unpublished content (not cached). Any ideas on how to retrieve unpublished content via umbracoHelper?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the ContentService as Mark pointed out, you can't use umbracoHelper to get unpublished content.

```
var contentService = ApplicationContext.Current.Services.ContentService;
var unpublishedContent = contentService.GetById(1234);
```

Full umbraco document on ContentService can be found here:
https://our.umbraco.org/documentation/reference/management/services/contentservice